# Ошибка ClickHouse Code: 10, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Not found column equals(catalog_id, 1041) in block

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Имеется Materialized база, данные реплицируюся нормально, в базе данные есть

Если выполнить запрос

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT P.id, 
    P.name, 
    P.catalog_id
FROM products P 
WHERE 
    P.name ILIKE '%Легкие%'
```

То получим результат:

```
   |name                                                                                                |catalog_id|brand_id|
---|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|----------|--------|
915|Подвеска "Легкие"                                                                                   |      5287|   15837|
990|Кроссовки/Кроссовки текстильные/Кроссовки женские летние/кроссовки легкие/Кроссовки спортивные      |      1053|   24390|
781|Брюки женские / Брюки прямые / Легкие брюки на резинке                                              |      1041|    1176|
```

Но если в запрос добавить AND catalog_id = N

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT P.id, 
    P.name, 
    P.catalog_id
FROM products P 
WHERE 
    P.name ILIKE '%Легкие%' AND P.catalog_id = 5287;
```

Или же так:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT P.id, 
    P.name, 
    P.catalog_id,
    P.brand_id 
FROM products P 
WHERE 
    P.catalog_id = 5287 AND P.brand_id = 15837;
```

То получаю ошибки

```
SQL Error [10]: ClickHouse exception, code: 10, Code: 10, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Not found column equals(catalog_id, 5287) in block: while executing 'INPUT : 1 -> equals(catalog_id, 5287) UInt8 : 1' (version 21.3.4.25 (official build))
```

```
SQL Error [10]: ClickHouse exception, code: 10, Code: 10, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Not found column equals(brand_id, 15837) in block: while executing 'INPUT : 0 -> equals(brand_id, 15837) UInt8 : 0' (version 21.3.4.25 (official build))
```

Почему так происходит? как выйти из этой ситуации?

Структура

```
CREATE TABLE analyzer.products
(

    `id` Int32,

    `product_id` Int32,

    `catalog_id` Int32,

    `brand_id` Int32,

    `name` Nullable(String),

    `description` Nullable(String),

    `supplier` Nullable(String),

    `marketplace` String,

    `letter` String,

    `isNew` UInt8,

    `isSoldOut` UInt8,

    `created` DateTime,

    `updated` DateTime,

    `_sign` Int8 MATERIALIZED 1,

    `_version` UInt64 MATERIALIZED 1
)
ENGINE = ReplacingMergeTree(_version)
PARTITION BY intDiv(id,
 4294967)
ORDER BY (product_id,
 catalog_id,
 brand_id,
 letter,
 updated,
 id)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Comment: покажите схему materialized view; попробуйте запрос без использования alias *P*

Comment: Без алиасов не проходит, такая же ошибка id
product_id
catalog_id
brand_id
name
description
supplier
marketplace
letter
isNew
isSoldOut
created
updated
_sign
_version

Answer (score 0):

Похоже MaterializedMySQL не поддерживает составные запросы через AND, пришлось отказаться от MySQL и полностью мигрировать на ClickHouse